# Get value from reified generic without using reflection

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'm building a driver that has to encode values (INT4 -> ByteArray as example) and decode values (ByteArray -> INT4 as example)

I have two interfaces, `Encodable` and `Decodable` (stripped down here to make it more clear what they do)

```
interface Encodable

interface Decodable {
    val code: Int
}
```

`Encodable` is used on the class itself and `Decodable` is used on the companion object like this

```
class INT4 : Encodable {
    companion object : Decodable {
        override val code: Int
            get() = 1
    }
}

class FLOAT : Encodable {
    companion object : Decodable {
        override val code: Int
            get() = 2
    }
}
```

The assumption here is that every Encodable class has a Decodable companion object that implements Decodable that can either give me a decode code or has the method itself to do the decoding back to an Encodable. Let's keep it simple and just focus on getting the code.

```
inline fun <reified T : Encodable> decode(byteArray: ByteArray): T {
    val code = (T::class.companionObjectInstance as Decodable).code
    print(code)
    // decode byte array using code
    ...
}
```

So doing the following

```
println(decode<INT4>(someEncodedByteArray)) // prints 1
println(decode<FLOAT>(someEncodedByteArray)) // prints 2
```

Running a profiler, it shows that this line of code

```
    val code = (T::class.companionObjectInstance as Decodable).code
```

is a performance bottleneck, most likely since it relies on reflection

```
import kotlin.reflect.full.companionObjectInstance
```

Is there a way to get to the companion object somehow without using reflection?

The best I could find so far is to manually map each of the 100s of types which doesn't feel like it's optimal

Create a map which will translate the class' simpleName to a Decodable, and list each of the Encodables inside the Mapping's init block.

```
object Mapping {
    val map = mutableMapOf<String, Decodable>()
    init {
        INT4
        FLOAT
    }
}
```

Inside each of the Decodables, have an init that would add it to the Map:

```
class INT4 : Encodable {
    companion object : Decodable {
        init {
            Mapping.map[checkNotNull(INT4::class.simpleName)] = INT4
        }
        override val code: Int
            get() = 1
    }
}

class FLOAT : Encodable {
    companion object : Decodable {
        init {
            Mapping.map[checkNotNull(FLOAT::class.simpleName)] = FLOAT
        }
        override val code: Int
            get() = 2
    }
}
```

Make sure to reference Mapping somewhere on application startup so it can map all those Decodables.

So now the code lookup becomes a map lookup, but `T::class.simpleName` is still using reflection.

```
checkNotNull(Mapping.map[checkNotNull(T::class.simpleName)]).code
```

At least I'm no longer relying on kotlin-reflect to make it happen.

Also open to merging `Encodable` and `Decodable` into one interface if it can be solved this way.

```
interface Codable {
    val code: Int
}

class INT4 : Codable {
    companion object : Codable {
        override val code: Int
            get() = 1
    }
    override val code: Int
        get() = INT4.code
}

class FLOAT : Codable {
    companion object : Codable {
        override val code: Int
            get() = 2
    }
    override val code: Int
        get() = FLOAT.code
}
```

Any ideas on how to make `decode<INT4>(someByteArray)` get the correct code so it can do the decoding without using reflection and without having to pass an instance of INT4 into `decode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this is possible without using reflection, duplicating the code or using some kind of a compiler plugin. However, because you already started looking for pragmatic solutions including hacks, then maybe the easiest is to simply cache the resolved decodables?

```kotlin
val cache = mutableMapOf<KClass<out Encodable>, Decodable>()

inline fun <reified T : Encodable> decode(byteArray: ByteArray): T {
    val code = cache.getOrPut(T::class) { T::class.companionObjectInstance as Decodable }.code
    print(code)
    // decode byte array using code
    ...
}
```

It uses reflection, but only once per each Encodable/Decodable. `KClass` are singletons, so it should store only a single entry per class. Also, I believe `T::class` itself should be pretty quick, the bottleneck is probably in `companionObjectInstance`.

You may need to protect it against the concurrent access.

If you target JVM, I would also test the performance while using `KClass` vs `Class`. Java's `Class` could be faster to acquire, even if theoretically it requires more Kotlin code.

**Update:**

If targeting JVM, it is also worth looking into the [ClassValue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassValue.html) as a potentially better alternative to a simple map (thanks Jan Vladimir Mostert and Sam Cooper for pointing this out).

Comment: This is actually a brilliant pragmatic solution; the cache hit ratio should be like 99.999%

Going to keep it open for a day or two to see if perhaps somebody found some really strange way of making it work.

Comment: Instead of using the class directly as a key, ClassValue can do it slightly more efficiently apparently: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassValue.html#get-java.lang.Class-

Thanks Sam Cooper for pointing me towards this interesting class

Comment: Ohh wow, never heard of it tbh, but it really looks like a better alternative to map.

Comment: I added that info to the answer - for a future reference.

Comment: I built a prototype now; that computeValue inside ClassValue is only called once per type, so you can literally just list all the Decodables, loop through them until you find a class whose simpleName matches the type's simplename, then you get rid of reflection completely. 

Slack discussion for reference:
https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C09222272/p1709037918880929?thread_ts=1709021151.624249&cid=C09222272